Face "recognition" using mediapipe
I'm using mediapipe to detect faces in a web camera live stream. I have a function to capture 50 face images from the stream and save it locally. then save all the facial features to a pkl file using mediapipe face mesh. I've tried to compare the saved features with the live stream face features but getting stuck somewhere. Is there a solution to this? Can I use deepface or opencv or any other algo to recognize data while the face detection part is done by mediapipe?
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import streamlit as st
import os
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu

logo_path = "logo2.png"
title_path = "title.png"

with st.sidebar:

    st.image(logo_path, width=300)
    st.image(title_path, use_column_width=True)

    # st.title("Face Recognition System")

    selected = option_menu(
        menu_title="Main Menu",  # required
        options=["Main Feed", "Add New", "Entry History"],  # required
        icons=["camera-video", "person-add", "clock-history"],  # optional
        menu_icon="house",  # optional
        default_index=0,  # optional
        styles={
            "H1": {"color": "orange", "font-size": "25px"},
        },
    )

if selected == "Main Feed":
    mp_face_detection = mp.solutions.face_detection
    mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh

    st.title("Live Camera Feed")
    FRAME_WINDOW = st.image([])

    # Use Streamlit caching to initialize camera once
    @st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
    def initialize_camera():
        return cv2.VideoCapture(0)


    camera = initialize_camera()

    # Directory to save captured frames and embeddings
    SAVE_DIR = "captured_data"
    os.makedirs(SAVE_DIR, exist_ok=True)

    frame_count = 0
    MAX_FRAMES = 50
    face_landmarks_list = []

    # Input field and dropdown for name
    name_input = st.text_input("Enter the name:")
    name_type = st.selectbox("Type:", ["Staff", "Visitor", "Special"])

    # Place the button in the main panel
    capture_button = st.button("Capture 50 Faces")

    # Custom notification box
    notification_box = st.empty()


    def show_notification(message, success=True):
        if success:
            notification_box.success(f":white_check_mark: {message}")
        else:
            notification_box.error(message)


    def capture_faces(name):
        global frame_count
        global face_landmarks_list

        # Generate a unique ID for this capture session
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
        unique_id = uuid.uuid4().hex[:8]
        unique_folder_name = f"{timestamp}_{unique_id}"

        with mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(static_image_mode=True, max_num_faces=1, min_detection_confidence=0.5) as face_mesh:
            while frame_count < MAX_FRAMES:
                _, frame = camera.read()
                frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

                # Use MediaPipe for face detection
                with mp_face_detection.FaceDetection(min_detection_confidence=0.5) as face_detection:
                    results = face_detection.process(frame_rgb)

                    if results.detections:
                        for detection in results.detections:
                            ih, iw, _ = frame.shape
                            bboxC = detection.location_data.relative_bounding_box
                            xmin, ymin, width, height = int(bboxC.xmin * iw), int(bboxC.ymin * ih), \
                                int(bboxC.width * iw), int(bboxC.height * ih)

                            # Draw rectangle around the face
                            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, ymin), (xmin + width, ymin + height), (0, 255, 0), 2)

                            # Crop the frame to capture only the face area
                            face_frame = frame[ymin:ymin + height, xmin:xmin + width]

                            # Convert frame to RGB for face mesh
                            frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(face_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

                            # Extract facial features using MediaPipe FaceMesh
                            results_mesh = face_mesh.process(frame_rgb)

                            if results_mesh.multi_face_landmarks:
                                # Flatten landmarks
                                landmarks = [list((lm.x, lm.y, lm.z)) for lm in
                                             results_mesh.multi_face_landmarks[0].landmark]
                                face_landmarks_list.append(landmarks)

                            # Save cropped face frame locally
                            save_path = os.path.join(SAVE_DIR, f"{name}_{unique_folder_name}")
                            os.makedirs(save_path, exist_ok=True)
                            frame_filename = os.path.join(save_path, f"face_{frame_count}.jpg")
                            cv2.imwrite(frame_filename, cv2.cvtColor(face_frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
                            frame_count += 1

                FRAME_WINDOW.image(frame)

        # Save face landmarks as a pickle file inside the subfolder
        pickle_file_path = os.path.join(save_path, f"{name}_{unique_folder_name}_landmarks.pkl")
        with open(pickle_file_path, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(face_landmarks_list, f)

        # Show notification in the sidebar
        show_notification(f"{name} has been added")


    # Streaming loop
    while True:
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        if not ret:
            st.write('Camera disconnected!')
            break

        # Use MediaPipe for face detection
        with mp_face_detection.FaceDetection(min_detection_confidence=0.5) as face_detection:
            results = face_detection.process(frame)

            if results.detections:
                for detection in results.detections:
                    ih, iw, _ = frame.shape
                    bboxC = detection.location_data.relative_bounding_box
                    xmin, ymin, width, height = int(bboxC.xmin * iw), int(bboxC.ymin * ih), \
                        int(bboxC.width * iw), int(bboxC.height * ih)

                    # Draw rectangle around the face
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, ymin), (xmin + width, ymin + height), (0, 255, 0), 2)

                    # Add text "Unknown" above the rectangle if the person is unknown
                    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                    cv2.putText(frame, 'Unknown', (xmin, ymin - 10), font, 0.9, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        FRAME_WINDOW.image(frame)

        if capture_button and name_input:
            name = f"{name_input}_{name_type}"
            capture_faces(name)
            capture_button = False

if selected == "Add New":
    st.title(f"You have selected {selected}")
if selected == "Entry History":
    st.title(f"You have selected {selected}")```


I've found that face embeddings are not enough to recognize faces. Moving to FaceNet

Face detection using mediapipe + Face embedding using FaceNet (or any equivalent face encoder) is the right approach. Note that mediapipe's face mesh output consists only of facial landmarks (e.g: coordinate/position of eyes, nose, etc), it's not useful for recognition purpose (i.e: distinguishing people's identity) .

Can checkout this https://github.com/topics/face-recognition for open-sourced face encoder (to generate face embedding for distinguishing identity)

Finally, check Insightface as an universal solution for face detection, landmarking and embedding.
